# Iterating over javascript object and valueOf toString methods

Tags: javascript, object

```
var x = {
    article: "bla bla bla ",
    journal: "le monde ",
    magazine: "playboy"
};

for (var i in x) { 
    alert(i + " "+ x[i]);
}
```

Every JS object has a `valueOf` and a `toString` method. Why can't I see them when I iterate over the properties of the `x` object?

Comment: Can't see what exactly ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in FF. Might be a browser specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The engine specifically *hides* these methods from enumeration.

The purpose of this is to allow to iterate over Object properties without being annoyed by the object's prototypal properties. This way you can iterate over Array indices, use Objects as hash tables and iterate over its properties.

This can however be easily broken. For example if you use a custom method in Object.property, it will suddenly appear during the enumeration of all objects' properties:

```
var obj = { foo: 0 };

Object.prototype.bar = 1;

// prints 'foo' and 'bar'
for (var k in obj) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

This is makes it dangerous to extend Object.prototype.

You can test if a property comes from the object itself or it's prototype by using the [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method:

```
// prints 'foo'
for (var k in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(a)) continue;
    console.log(k);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) do define non-enumerable properties, if you don't care of old browsers:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'bar', {value: 1, enumerable: false});

// prints 'foo'
for (var k in obj) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

Comment: Why does it do it so inconsistently? Why are the object prototype methods hidden from enumeration, but array prototype methods aren't?

Comment: Array prototypes should be hidden from you. Only libraries that define them that way wouldn't be.

Comment: @PeterOlson I believe Array's default prototype properties don't appear in enumeration. `length` doesn't, for instance. As @ NotAName said, the properties you see are very probably coming from a library you use.

Answer (score 0):

They are not enumerable properties. Try  Object.getOwnPropertyNames. Only works in some browsers:

This DOESNT check proto though, so you need to do something very complicated:

```
var x, y, z, getAllKeys;
getAllKeys = function (obj,ar) {
    ar = ar || [new Array];
    ar[0] = ar[0].concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    if (obj !== Function.prototype && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
        getAllKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj),ar);
    }
    return ar[0];
}
console.log (getAllKeys(new Array));
for (x in y = getAllKeys(z = new Array)) {
    var key = y[x];
    var value = z[y[x]];
}
```

Blame JavaScript for being ridiculous and looking like assembly, maybe jASM would be a better name? (joke)

Comment: Are you aware that `Object.__proto__` refers to `Function.prototype` and not to the `null` value? And if you are using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, why don't use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of the non-standard and deprecated `__proto__`?

Comment: It'll never be removed at this rate. But it's also possible some browsers have Object.getOwnPropertyNames but not Object.getPrototypeOf. Also nility was just something random. I could have put null otherwise. :P

Comment: Nice work, I've never seen a browser that implements `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` but not `Object.getPrototypeOf`... Anyway this might come up in the future, in ES.Next, they will implement a `Object.getPropertyNames` method, I made a similar function some time ago: https://gist.github.com/633782